# scalar to long conversion

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I calculated the sum of pixels values of gray scale image and stored the sum in "long" ,
when I try to compare this value to another long as follow:

```
 if (sum == Original_Sum[0])
     sum1++;
//original sum is array of type long
```

I get this error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cv::Scalar (__cdecl *)(cv::InputArray)' to 'double'

casting or `.val[0]` didn't work, any suggestion? 
thanks in advance...

Comment: Post some more relevant code. What is `.val[0]`? What is `Original_Sum[0]`?

Comment: These data types: `sum` and `Original_Sum[0]` are almost certainly not either of type `long` as you've suggested. Both the error message and your mention of `.val[0]` confirms that. Please post the declarations / definitions.

Comment: I defined them as long, but the result of sum is treated as vector . I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you declared those variables?

```
long Original_Sum[1];
long sum;
long sum1;
```

Because if they were declared like this, then there is nothing wrong with your code as far as i can see

Also, .val is not a member of type long